# Haml -Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am facing a weird error in my code while using HAML where my code is working on my Local Machine but when I am deploying it I am getting the following error

> ActionView::Template::Error (Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal.):

My code looks like this

```
  %td{ :style => 'width:10px' }
= link_to('Dashboard',   dashboard_admin_clients_account_path(client)) if client.is_member?
= link_to('Edit',   edit_admin_clients_account_path(client))
- if client.removed_at.nil?
  = link_to('Delete', admin_clients_account_path(client), :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete')
- else
  = link_to('Restore', restore_admin_clients_account_path(client))
```

I am new to HAML

Comment: I had some trouble finding the cause of this problem because the error was inside a partial rendered with `render`, but the stack trace pointed to the parent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. If you want your links to be inside the %td, they should be 1 tab righter (td - 0 tab, links - 1 tabs from the left side)
2. you should use the same method to make indents (for example always use tab instad of spaces).
3. it looks like the problem is not in this code. Is it partitial or part of some other code?

**Because 'illegal nesting' usually happens when you do like this:**

```
%td{ :style => 'width:10px' }
    justtext
      =link_to ....
```

**Try this code:**

```
%td{ :style => 'width:10px' }
    = link_to('Dashboard',   dashboard_admin_clients_account_path(client)) if client.is_member?
    = link_to('Edit',   edit_admin_clients_account_path(client))
    - if client.removed_at.nil?
        = link_to('Delete', admin_clients_account_path(client), :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete')
    - else
        = link_to('Restore', restore_admin_clients_account_path(client))
```

Comment: yes this is a part of my partial but the code is working fine on my local machine