# I can't get a search bar to appear in my Ruby application

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a Ruby application and am trying to implement a search function. I have the code to handle the search request but I can't get the search bar to appear, I have coded it into my `application.html.haml` but I get an Illegal Nesting error. What am I doing wrong?

```
%body  
    %header  
        .wrapper.clearfix  
            #logo= link_to "Scribble", root_path  
                <li><%= form_tag(search_path, method: :get) do %>  
                    <%= text_field_tag(:post_title, params[:post_title]) %>  
                    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>  
                <% end %>  
            %nav  
                - if user_signed_in?  
                    = link_to current_user.name, edit_user_registration_path  
                    = link_to "Add New Inspiration", new_post_path, class: "button"  
                - else  
                    = link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path  
                    = link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, class: "button"  
    %p.notice= notice
```

Comment: Can you please post the error stack trace?  Also see if this  link helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13524362/259889

Comment: The part within `#logo` doesn't look like valid Haml.

Comment: Hi @Stefan, I don't know why it is greyed out in this code but that part works fine, it shows a logo that when clicked brings the users back to the home page. That part works fine, but do you think it is affecting what is beneath it?

Comment: @C13 yes, that is what I meant by "within". You can't just mix Haml and HTML / ERB.

Comment: @Stefan I took out that line and I'm still getting the original problem which is that there's an error when I want the search bar to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through 5th to 9th lines, you have erb, where the rest of the template written in HAML.

This code should work as expected

```
%body  
    %header  
        .wrapper.clearfix  
            #logo= link_to "Scribble", root_path  
            %li
                = form_tag(search_path, method: :get) do 
                    = text_field_tag(:post_title, params[:post_title])
                    = submit_tag "Search"
            %nav  
                - if user_signed_in?  
                    = link_to current_user.name, edit_user_registration_path  
                    = link_to "Add New Inspiration", new_post_path, class: "button"  
                - else  
                    = link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path  
                    = link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, class: "button"  
    %p.notice= notice
```

Comment: Hi, No that code won't work for me, I get this error 'Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %div and nested within it.' around the line %li , I don't know what this error means nor how to fix it.

Comment: @C13 yeah, right, sorry. Changed the answer, should work now

Comment: That's not working either, it says there are lots of syntax errors in it, 18 to be precise. I don't know what's wrong with that code at all, I can't understand why there's no search box appearing.

Comment: @C13 can you post a few first lines, please?

Comment: I turned the server off for an hour and restarted it, the search bar is appearing now... Thank you! Now I have an issue with the search results, thanks for the help Nikita Misharin!

Comment: @C13 No worries. Although you can choose the answer as the best, if it helped

Answer (score 0):

you are using ERB syntax inside HAML view so it should be HAML syntax and not ERB

```
.wrapper.clearfix
  = form_tag(search_path, method: :get) do
    = text_field_tag(:post_title, params[:post_title])
    = submit_tag "Search"
```

Comment: I get an error saying "Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %div and nested within it." on the line beginning with ' = form_tag '